# Disable frequency resampling in pulseaudio

Tags: alsa, pulseaudio

I have a sound card that supports different playback frequencies, I want pulseaudio not to resample the frequency of the track being played if (always) this frequency is supported by the sound card.

I know that there is the `avoid-resampling` parameter, I tried to set it, but it does not work, resampling occurs, if I change the `default-sample-rate` parameter to the frequency of the track being played, then resampling does not happen.

I can’t drop pulseaudio and leave only one alsa since I need pulseeffects support. Maybe there is a way to turn off this damn resampling, maybe through the alsa settings, pulseaudio works through it.